# Unable to Build using MAVEN with ERROR - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile

Tags: java, maven

I have been trying to build a code using maven. But I am stuck with an error.
The code is available on this github repo. [google-play-crawler](https://github.com/Akdeniz/google-play-crawler)

My system configurations as shown by maven is followning:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:28+0530)
Maven home: /Users/tushar/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Following is the Maven trace for the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project googleplaycrawler: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project googleplaycrawler: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here is the pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.akdeniz</groupId>
    <artifactId>googleplaycrawler</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Google Play Crawler</name>
    <url>https://github.com/Akdeniz/google-play-crawler</url>

    <description>Play with Google Play API :)</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>protoc-plugin</id>
            <url>http://sergei-ivanov.github.com/maven-protoc-plugin/repo/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fork>true</fork
                    <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.cli.googleplay</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <protocExecutable>protoc</protocExecutable>
                    <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf/</protoSourceRoot>
                    <languageSpecifications>
                        <LanguageSpecification>
                            <language>JAVA</language>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        </LanguageSpecification>
                    </languageSpecifications>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I just [reported this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-274) because I don't think Maven's behaviour is acceptable...

Comment: And yet, it is still happening with `maven-compiler-plugin` `3.5.1` with no improvement in printed error messages.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your Maven is reading Java version as 1.6.0_65, Where as the pom.xml says the version is 1.7.

Try installing the required verison.

If already installed check your $JAVA_HOME environment variable, it should contain the path of Java JDK 7. If you dont find it, fix your environment variable.

also remove the lines

```xml
 <fork>true</fork>
     <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
```

from the `pom.xml`

Comment: That syntax is supposed to work in order to support people needing to target multiple JDKs

Comment: Installing JDK 7 worked for me. I also had to change the Project JDK.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed the fork and it started working.

Comment: @shshank I have the JDK 1.8. What I do? do I have to downgrade my JDK?

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run (default) on project project: Error executing ant tasks: Warning: Could not find file /home/shehbaz/Desktop/mvn/e6/src/main/resources/env.test.properties to copy. -> [Help 1]

Comment: I have this error also. while file with name env.test.properties is there.

Answer (score 10):

For my situation, I switched the value of "fork" to false, such as `<fork>false</fork>`. I do not understand why.

Comment: Really, sounds strange. Tried today to comile some old project with jdk 9 and your suggestion helped me

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar errors and eventually found just that cleaning the build folder resolved my issue.

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: bravo, mvn clean, then mvn package did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When compared the java version mentioned in the pom.xml file is different and the **JAVA_HOME** env variable was pointing to different version of **jdk**.

Have the **JAVA_HOME** and `pom.xml` updated to the same **jdk** installation path

Answer (score 1):

If JDK installed but still not working.

In Eclipse follow below steps:-
Window  --> Preference --> Installed JREs -->Change path of JRE to JDK(add).

Answer (score 1):

For me, I changed
`C:\apps\Java\jdk1.8_162\bin\javac.exe` to
`C:\apps\Java\jdk1.8_162\bin\javacpl.exe`
since there was no executable with that name in the bin folder.  That worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had he same problem even the correct JAVA-Version and JAVA_HOME variable was set. (In my case Java 11).

**Switching** to another Java-Vendor **from AdoptOpenJDK to Corretto** solved it.

You can use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/install) to change easily and quick between different Java-Versions and vendors. (JAVA_HOME variable will set automatically correct by SDKMAN).

**Install SDKMAN by**

```bash
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

then enter in the terminal:

```bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

to ensure installation was successful:

```bash
sdk version
```

**Install Java 7:**

```bash
sdk install java 7.0.322-zulu
sdk default java 7.0.322-zulu
```

To check the versions, runtime and vendor:

```bash
java --version
mvn -v
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this trick worked

I have to end java task from the task manager, because it was not able to clean.

Rebuild it again and it worked.

Note: am using windows system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar exception. Posting here in case it helps someone in future. My SpringBoot application was looking for properties from a `application.yml` file. But I copy-pasted the properties from a smiliar looking `application.properties` file. Please remember, format of both the files are not same.