# Maven Compilation Failure but no errors found

Tags: java, maven

I'm running a maven build in Java 8, using compatibility target Java 6. When I try to build with Maven in Eclipse (just this project mind you, all other projects in my workspace build just fine), I get a compilation failure from maven, but maven doesn't list any actual errors except a generic MojoFailureException. When I compile through eclipse itself (using ANT or straight Java, there are no compilation errors). Also when I build on a remote machine using Jenkins and the same source code, there also are no problems using maven. It's definitely a local problem and I can't quite figure it out.

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ 
DataAdapterFB1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 58 source files to C:\Users\user\Desktop\GitRepo\FB1DataAdapter\code\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.460 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-18T08:20:37-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/489M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project DataAdapterFB1: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project DataAdapterFB1: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1165)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Relevant compiler plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <executable>${JAVA_6_HOME}\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${JAVA_6_HOME}\jre\lib\rt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Hello, did you try to use debug mode ? `mvn -X ...`

Comment: Sure did. It's too large to add to the post though. I didn't see anything relevant in the results though.

Comment: Can you try removing all except `source` and `target` from the compiler plugin configuration?

Comment: Have you used lambdas or functional interfaces or diamond operators in your source code?

Comment: I just ran this and now it gave an error: [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: @mallikarjun - No I haven't.

Comment: You mentioned using Java 8 but it seems you are referring a Java 6 environment `${JAVA_6_HOME}\bin\javac.exe` Perhaps those properties are set differently in the specific systems?

Comment: So I found out that it is the ${JAVA_6_HOME} variable. It's defined earlier in the pom file as a hard coded path. Anyway to make that generic?

Comment: Set JAVA_HOME in the OS environment instead of pom.xm and then try again.

Comment: If your project is managed across different machines(linux/windows) and multiple  developers, I will recomennd to use [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) plugin and supply  --global-toolchains file according to their machine JDK paths.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Esp @rodrigoap, your suggestion uncovered the root cause.

Comment: I had this problem with low RAM. The compiler crashed silently.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with using JDK 11 to build a Maven project that targets Java 7. Try removing `<fork>true</fork>` (or set it to `false` instead), and that should fix it. (h/t to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39657410/278800)

I don't actually know what the root cause is, though. My guess is that some part of the java environment isn't being passed to the forked compile process, like e.g. `JAVA_HOME`. Or maybe it's because I'm using `jenv` to set my java version, and that doesn't work with the forked process.

Comment: Although this did not make my project compile, it revealed the underlying error :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a legacy project and I came across the same issue.  Steve K's answer shed some light for me as well.

Here is the maven-compiler-plugin section in my project's pom.xml
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with built in maven and JDK8 in a Windows environment.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>${jdk.home}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm able to get the compiler running by making the value of `<fork>true</fork>` to false.

### The reasoning behind

If the flag is false, Maven will use the same JVM process that brought up its process to do the compilation, which is fine for me as I am using Java 8 to bootstrap my Maven process.

If the flag is true, maven will try to fork (create) a new JVM process to do the job, and it will use the javac compiler defined in the `<executable>` section to do so.  
In my case, there is a `${jdk.home}` variable that needs to be injected before running the Maven build.  Clearly someone in our team forgot to tell the new joiner regarding for this setup.

There is some performance penalty of making the `<fork>` flag false though, so the ideal way is to leave it true but make sure the path in `<executable>` is valid.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#fork

Comment: thank you for your explanation, it helped me to resolve the problem in question!