# Maven Spring Boot compilation failure

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

One of my Java Spring Boot projects stopped compiling the assets. Can anyone give me an idea as to why? I mention that I haven't changed anything, it simply stopped working from one day to another for some reason.

```
[ERROR] symbol:   class QRegulation
[ERROR] location: package ro.gss.database.entity
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My pom.xml file looks like this: (the dependencies are not all here due to the code to text ratio that stackoverflow requires)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.gss</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
    <version>1.x.y-SIMSI-VERSION</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>database</name>
    <description>Database micro-service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <querydsl.version>3.7.0</querydsl.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <poi.version>4.0.0</poi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>src/main/java/ro/gss/app/jpa/domain/entity</source>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor,lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            <options>
                                <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/java/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

By using mvn -e clean package I got the following extra details:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project database: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can run `mvn -X clean package` or `mvn -e clean package` to know more behind this. Anyway, you should provide more information about your pom.xml since there is no way to know what's going on

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution

`mvn clean install` - It will clear any compiled files you have, making sure that you're really compiling each module from scratch. Make sure you are connected to the internet

---

EDIT:

Delete your .m2 repository

```
Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2/repository
Windows – C:\Users\yourUsername\.m2
```

Refer Maven Lifecycle [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

---

- Set Java Build Path as jdk

> Right click project ->Java Build Path ->Select Libraries tab ->Select
>   JRE System Library ->Click Edit button ->Click Installed JREs-> add
>   tick to box ->click Edit ->Click Directory->Select jdk

- Specifi which kind of jdk version you installed

> Right-click project ->Project Facets ->tick java and select java
>   version->Apply ->Ok

- Update project

> Right-click on "project"->Go to Maven->Update

---

Recheck the Java version you are using for Project and current Set version. It should be the same.
according to your error, You may get a solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218486/unable-to-build-using-maven-with-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven/28922645)

Comment: mvn clean install has the same result as my issue

Comment: tried all of them and in vain. I am working on a Mac if it gives out any clue. I really have no idea what happened.

Comment: Check the version and set the correct Path and make sure you are connected to the internet. Also, refer to an updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions**

1. You should try

   ```
   mvn clean package
   ```
2. Or if you have multiple modules, you can try:

   ```
   mvn  clean  package -pl modulename -am
   ```