# Deployment of Spring Boot Project to Google App-Engine fails with Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I keep trying to deploy my Spring-Boot application to Google appengine. I am using the SDK and the maven plugin.

The Spring-Boot-Application is running perfectly on my localhost, but when i try to deploy it with `mvn package appengine:deploy`I get the following error message:

```
BUILD FAILURE
Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project TestProject: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project TestProject: App Engine application deployment failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    ...
```

Interesting is the fact, that a similar error occurs when trying to deploy to Microsoft Azure.

I followed the official tutorial from google (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/) and tried a few other tutorials as well. Nothing seems to fix the issue for me.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>de.myname</groupId>  
  <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  <parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version> 
  </parent>  

  <dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>  


  <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>  


  <build> 
    <plugins> 

      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      </plugin>  

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <version>1</version>
          <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

My app.yaml looks like the following:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you presented really depends on the size and scope of the Spring Boot application you are working on. I have however followed the deployment steps that were provided from your link. Here are my findings:

You are getting MojoExecutionException according to your error output. This error is not generated by Maven itself, but due to a plugin. Plugins trigger this error message to signal a problem in your configuration of information retrieved from the pom.xml file. You may want to look into that, by updating all plugins, if possible. 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

You would need to make sure you configure your pom.xml file correctly. Perhaps you are missing certain dependencies that your project needs in order to run.
The version of Java you are deploying your application should match the one listed in your pom.xml file.
[Unable to Build using MAVEN with ERROR - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218486/unable-to-build-using-maven-with-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven)