# cant build project using maven - compability error

Tags: java, maven

Im trying to get a few old projects running again and as a starter I would like to build the example codes here: [github.com/skadistats/clarity-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218486/unable-to-build-using-maven-with-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven) 
You can find the .pom [here](https://github.com/skadistats/clarity-examples/blob/master/pom.xml)

trying to build this spits out the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.647 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-09T14:43:24+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar
 (default-jar) on project clarity-examples: Execution default-jar of goal org.ap
ache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar failed: An API incompatibility was e
ncountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar: ja
va.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
```

Ive been trying to follow the advice given [in this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218486/unable-to-build-using-maven-with-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven), but couldnt resolve the issue.

```
C:\>mvn -version
C:\
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: c:\Users\MyName\Downloads\clarity\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 14, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-14
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

unsure if my JAVA_HOME is set correctly, echoing it certainly works
[environmental variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gib6j.png)

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade maven-jar-plugin to the most recent one ....cause version 2.6 is more than five years old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this: with Java up to version 13 it works, in version 14 the maven-jar-plugin version 2.6 gives that error.
You can either use Java 13, or change the pom: at line 72 put 3.2.0 instead of 2.6 for the versione of the maven-jar-plugin